# Is it ok to stretch a steel fork from 90mm to 100mm?

Tags: fork

I want to fit a 100mm front wheel on it but the current wheel seems to be 90mm wide..

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are you trying to increase the wheel size? Give us more details and we may have an alternative.  Grab-and-yank wiil bend one but not both.  Good work for planning before doing.

Answer (score 5):

You can spread steel forks safely (never spread aluminum/carbon fiber), and its not a trivial task to do at home, since you need to keep the fork blades spaced symmetrically and you don't have the same type of leverage available for the rear triangle. Then re-bend the axle mounts, as Criggie points out in the comments.

Sheldon Brown has [some tips](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html#frameadjustment) on how to do it (pull the fork apart, check for alignment, use a rubber mallet when necessary), but I'd leave it to a shop if you can find one that can do it.

Comment: You'd have to bend the axle mounts back the other way to keep them parallel too.  If the fork uses disk mounts, then just don't bother - too risky.

Comment: 90 mm spaced forks aren't common (old low end things, track hubs sometimes). Never disc based afaik.